# Passing a const pointer... do I need to do it?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, parameter-passing

I have a struct of Foo:

```
struct Foo
{
};
```

I have a struct of Bar:

```
struct Bar
{
};
```

They are handled by 2 more structs which maintain (add/remove) a pointer array of each:

```
struct FooContainer
{
    Foo** FooList;

    // add(), remove() etc
};

struct BarContainer
{
    Bar** BarList;

    // add(), remove() etc
};
```

Now, what I WANT is another struct called Baz which links (in a one-to-many fashion) Foo to Baz. I can't (for reasons not explained here) refer to them by index, it must be by pointer/reference.

Something like this:

```
struct Baz
{
    Foo* foo;
    Bar* bar;
};
```

If I wanted to add a constructor to Baz which took these non-const pointers, how would I do it?

Baz should allow me to change which instance of Foo and Bar it points to... so it's pointers don't want to be const.

Do I pass the pointers into the constructor as const and then do something with them as I would if I were passing a reference to a struct? I then get issues with trying to set the value of a non-const pointer to a const pointer.

I hope this question makes sense...

Edit: Should I use reference instead of pointer?

Answer (score 3):

> Baz should allow me to change which instance of Foo and Bar it points to... so it's pointers don't want to be `const`.

That is correct, you don't want to store constant pointers. However, it does not prevent you to store pointers to `const`, which is not the same thing.

This sounds confusing, so here is an illustration using your `Baz` example:

```
struct Baz
{
    const Foo* foo;
    const Bar* bar;
    Baz(const Foo* newFoo, const Bar* newBar) : foo(newFoo), bar(newBar) {}
    void setFoo(const Foo* newFoo) { foo = newFoo; }
    void setBar(const Bar* newBar) { bar = newBar; }
};
```

everything is going to compile fine: it's `Foo` and `Bar` pointed to by `foo` and `bar` that are `const`, not the pointers themselves, which leaves you free to change the pointers as you wish.

This, on the other hand, is not going to compile:

```
struct Baz
{   // Note how const has moved to the other side of the asterisk
    Foo* const foo;
    Bar* const bar;
    Baz(Foo* newFoo, Bar* newBar) : foo(newFoo), bar(newBar) {}
    void setFoo(Foo* newFoo) { foo = newFoo; } // BROKEN!!!
    void setBar(Bar* newBar) { bar = newBar; } // BROKEN!!! 
};
```

Now the pointer, not the "pointee", is `const`, preventing you from changing `foo` or `bar` members.

Comment: This is what I thought. Why is it that when you pass a reference to a struct, you pass it as a const reference?

Comment: @Beakie You don't have to pass it as a `const` reference if you want an ability to change your `struct`. When you do not want to change it, you put `const` to give callers a significant flexibility in calling your function, because taking a `struct` by `const` reference lets callers pass a temporary. For example, if you have `void foo(const Baz& b)`, you can call it like this: `foo(Baz(p1, p2))`. Here, `Baz` is a temporary object, but it's OK because `foo` takes `Baz` by `const` reference. Without `const` this same call would not compile.